# creating database based on two dataframes

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I have two dataframes.

One is music.

| name | Date | Edition | Song_ID | Singer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| LA | 01.05.2009 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| Second | 13.07.2009 | 1 | 2 | 2 |
| Mexico | 13.07.2009 | 1 | 3 | 1 |
| Let's go | 13.09.2009 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| Hello | 18.09.2009 | 1 | 5 | (4,5) |
| Don't give up | 12.02.2010 | 2 | 6 | (5,6) |
| ZIC ZAC | 18.03.2010 | 2 | 7 | 7 |
| Blablabla | 14.04.2010 | 2 | 8 | 2 |
| Oh la la | 14.05.2011 | 3 | 9 | 4 |
| Food First | 14.05.2011 | 3 | 10 | 5 |
| La Vie est.. | 17.06.2011 | 3 | 11 | 8 |
| Jajajajajaja | 13.07.2011 | 3 | 12 | 9 |

And another dataframe called  singer

| Singer | nationality | Singer_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| JT Watson | USA | 1 |
| Rafinha | Brazil | 2 |
| Juan Casa | Spain | 3 |
| Kidi | USA | 4 |
| Dede | USA | 5 |
| Briana | USA | 6 |
| Jay Ado | UK | 7 |
| Dani | Australia | 8 |
| Mike Rich | USA | 9 |

Now I would like to create a database  called musicten from these two dataframes using sqlite3 but it says conn is not defined. What I done so far

```
import sqlite3
sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')
conn=sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS singer
          ([Singer_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [Singer] TEXT,[nationality] TEXT )
          ''')
          
c.execute('''
          CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS music
          ([Song_ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, [Singer_ID] INTEGER SECONDARY KEY, [name] TEXT, [DATE] DATE, [Edition] INTEGER)
          ''')
                     
conn.commit()
```

I would like to create a database.

Comment: You can declare `conn` like this `conn = sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')`

Comment: Did you forget `conn = sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')`?

Comment: Yes, but then I don't know how to finish the creating of database

Comment: Remove `sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')`

Comment: My main issue was to insert the values

Comment: I wrote I would like to create a database based on the two dataframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define you connection as below:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('musicten.db')
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the official tutorials? https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#tutorial https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#io-sql

Comment: I self used that https://datatofish.com/create-database-python-using-sqlite3/